# Error while navigating a website for scraping data

Tags: r, web-scraping, phantomjs, rvest, rselenium

I'm scraping data for a website , but while I navigate through the website using the command `remDr$navigate("http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs")`

it gives me error in command prompt

```
phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
[ERROR - 2017-06-28T05:01:51.466Z] Session [c5653e70-5bbe-11e7-9496-47f479558959] - page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: paramTraffic

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
[ERROR - 2017-06-28T05:01:51.467Z] Session [c5653e70-5bbe-11e7-9496-47f479558959] - page.onError - stack:
  initializeDSS (https://cdn.staticmb.com/scripts/header.js:1)

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
10:31:52.411 INFO - Done: [get: http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs]
```

But when I navigate through some other website it executes smoothly

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.r-project.org")

10:45:21.810 INFO - Executing: [get: http://www.r-project.org])
10:45:21.938 INFO - Done: [get: http://www.r-project.org]
```

This is snippet of my code

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
pJS <- phantomjs("C:/Users/user/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe",port = 4566L,version = "2.1.1",check = T,loglevel = c("INFO", "ERROR", "WARN", "DEBUG"), verbose = TRUE, retcommand = FALSE)

remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment&cityName=Thane&BudgetMin=5-Lacs&BudgetMax=10-Lacs")
```

Does any have any idea why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

> P.S:-- I'm using selenium server version 3.3.1 Windows 10 all my other
>   essential drivers are in same directory where my selenium server is
>   residing Using phantomjs-2.1.1-windows browser

Comment: ohh I see that.